# Is there a way to integrate AKS with azure ad b2c

Tags: azure-aks

Is there a way to integrate AKS with azure ad b2c
I am finding a way to associate ad b2c instead of azure ad.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with such an association? Administration / role based access control on AKS environment & components or using it for an application hosted in containers on AKS?

Comment: Through azure active directory we can achieve the authentication but wanted to know if there is a way for authenticating using b2c tenant for application hosted on Aks

Answer (score -1):

The question is not quite precise. You dont integrate azure AD B2C with AKS. You integrate B2C with the application that is hosted on the AKS. So you need to design authentication logic in your app.
Azure AD B2C supports applications that use protocols OAuth 2.0 or OpenID Connect.
See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types
or a sample app:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/blob/main/README_B2C.md